# Motion Detection of an 1D Array (neural network or other options?)

Tags: c++, vector, graph, detection, pattern-recognition

I am currently developing a project for the detection of different sounds. The software should analyze an incoming sound as a wave file and recognize certain tags. For some tags, I use neural networks, which works well too. Now, however, I have a tag that makes problems. It's about motion detection.

I want to know if the sound is rigid and stands still (slight variations are of course allowed) or if the sound may contain movement. To do this, I split the wave into frames of equal size and apply an FFT to get the spectrum. For the people here who are unfamiliar with the field, ... do not worry. You do not have to, because in the end only one graph comes out and I want to see if and how much this graph moves over time.

Here is a small example. I load a wave (in the picture on the top right) that looks very similar visually over time. However, you can see in the spectrum (bottom right) that the height proportions (higher frequencies) per frame decrease. I would like to recognize such movements somehow.

The example shows three frames. One frame per picture...
(Unfortunately, I can not post any pictures here)

Frame 1:
https://ruta-sound.com/other_stuff/img/frame0.png

Frame 2:
https://ruta-sound.com/other_stuff/img/frame1.png

Frame 3:
https://ruta-sound.com/other_stuff/img/frame2.png

Can somebody possibly give me an approach, how I can solve this problem?

For a better illustration, there is the spectrogram below left. Here you can see the complete spectrum over time. X represents the time and Y the frequencies. Again, you can see the movement well.

For a long time I have tried the following two ideas, but without success or wrongly implemented:

1st approach: Also a neural network, as well as the other tags (it works great there). I take the complete picture at the bottom left and give it to the input of the network, just like with an image recognition. So you have X * Y input neurons, a hidden layer with 2/3 times neurons and two output neurons for "movement" or just "no movement". As I said, the other attributes are wonderful, but this one does not bother with this one. Do I need any recurrent networks? If so, does anyone know anything?

2nd approach: I calculate the difference of the points in the spectrum from current to next frame and sum them. Suppose point 0 in the spectrum (lowest frequency) has the value "0.5" in frame 0, the value "0.5" in frame 1 and the value "0.6" in frame 2, then I would have a total of "0.1". I do that for all points and sum them together. The higher the value, the bigger the movement, right? Unfortunately not quite, because if there's just a kind of light shivering, so it goes slightly up and down from frame to frame, but does not move at all, then it still sums up and a movement is recognized, but hardly any is available.

Answer (score 0):

Sound recognition is still competitive.
No one can give you a solution where he can say this will work. Maybe someone who is very experienced in this field (+15 years in sound recognition).

To 1) You can use a recurrent neural network, but i wouldn't give them so much chance that they work good in this case. But it can. You should rather use a Bayes network. Bayes networks are used in word recognition of spoken words. Here is a link to the first paper i found: https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1998/AAAI98-024.pdf I haven't read it, just that you have an idea what i am talking about. Wikipedia should help too.

To 2) Clearly you can try more features with your neural network. By example the number of apex, the frequency of apex, gradients and so on. This can work, it worked for me for a problem with time depended data. Was as good as time prediction. 
In a perfect manner you make a lot of features, than you apply a principal component analysis (pca) or linear discriminant analysis (lda). This removes unimportant data which can confuse your neural network and makes train duration very high.

I would try 2 first, because it's less work. Just making more features and train your ANN again. By the way, one layer seem not much for that problem, even i don't know your number of features and outputs. Probably you should use 2 mid-layer at least.

If you don't get a solution with 2 you should decide by the result of 2 if you take RNN or Bayesian Network. If solution 2 with new features is bad i wouldn't try RNN because they are very similar. Bayesian Network are known to work good for time dependent data.